# How to use openCV to count the stack of the boxes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

What my goal is trying to generate an algorithm that can count the stack of boxes. Keep in mind that I cannot hard-code the threshold value because the boxes can come in different colour so I cannot convert it to binary image.

Boxes
[image: Boxes]

What I have tried is covert it to grayscale and use canny edge detector to get the all the edges like the figure below:

```py
kernel1 = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
#kernel3 = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel1, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel2, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow("blur", img)
# img = cv2.erode(img, kernel1, iterations=1)
# img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel2, iterations=1)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
canny = cv2.Canny(opening, 30, 120)
```

Canny
[image: canny]

After that i used the houghlines function to get all the lines. I have made an algorithm to remove all the vertical lines in the line lists. The figure below shows the results using this code

```py
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, np.pi / 200, 90, minLineLength=20, maxLineGap=10)
for line in range(0, len(lines)):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = lines[line][0]
    # cv2.line(show, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
# cv2.imshow('first', show)
result = []

# cannot delete directly from the array because inside the  for loop
# use dummy "result[]" to keep the lines that needed
# return the result back to the array after the for loop
print(len(lines))
for line in range(0, len(lines)):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = lines[line][0]
    if x1 == x2:
        continue
    angle = math.atan(float((y2 - y1)) / float((x2 - x1)))
    angle = angle * 180 / math.pi
    # print(angle)
    if abs(angle) <= 5 and ((y1 or y2) < (show.shape[0] - 30)):
        result.append(lines[line][0])
lines = result
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(len(lines))
data = []
for line in range(0, len(result)):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = lines[line]
    cv2.line(show, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #cv2.imshow('show2', show)
    data.append((y1 + y2) / 2)
```

Results
[image: results]

The result that I want is something like this:
[image: expected outcome]

I already have a K-mean clustering for grouping the lines so I dont mind the lines stacking each other. But for now, what are the pre-process skills or techniques that I need to achieve my expected outcome so that I can count the stacks of the boxes?

Planned and problems that i faced:

So what i have planned is i convert to grayscale and use canny edge to sketch out the edges. There is a problem here, the texts on the boxes are also sketched. I tried to remove the texts by using dilation, but this process also blur out the edges that i want. I have no idea how to get those edges lines but not the lines that detected from the texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scan vertically your edges image with horizontal ROI (say Rect(0,y,image_w,10) ) and count nonZero pixels in it. It will give you a histogram of pixels density along horizontal axis. Then you may need smooth it and find peaks. These peaks will give separation lines.